# How can i solve traceroute received packages error?

Tags: python, networking, traceroute

i'm a Student and i wrote a traceroute file for project in my school. 
When the package arrives a router about 10-12 hops from the begining, the router doesn't return any answer. 
In order to solve this problam i made a loop so the program will send the package till it receives an answer. Instead of it, it still doesn't receive any answer.
this is the code:

```
ip = '8.8.8.8'
ttl = 1
hops = []
packet = IP(dst=ip, ttl=ttl)/ICMP(type=8)
packet.show()
resp = sr1(packet, timeout=3)
while resp.src != '8.8.8.8':
    hops.append(resp.src)
    ttl += 1
    packet = IP(dst=ip, ttl=ttl) / ICMP(type=8)
    resp = sr1(packet, timeout=20)
    while resp is None:
        resp = sr1(packet, timeout=20)
hops.append(resp.src)

counter = 1
for i in hops:
    print('Hop Number ' + str(counter) + '--->' + i)
    counter += 1
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't expect a reply from every single hop, some servers just DON'T reply to any ICMP whatsoever, they are configured this way, and no amount of retries will help you get a reply. Just do a couple of retries, and take no reply from that hop as a given. Just like regular tracert.

Comment: There can be many reason an hop will give no answers, but heres a few:
-Hop is configured not to send ICMP Unreachable - ttl exceeded
-There's a firewall blocking the replies
-There's a routing issue preventing replies to arrive (can happen in MPLS backbones)

Usually you can try 3 attempts, if no reply, try the next hop. If you don't get any reply for 10 consecutive hops, you're not likely to get more.